# javascript asp.net core v.2.0 polling and redirecting on success

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

Ok, I've ventured into Javascript.. and are experiencing some troubles...

(I fake an pizza own that takes long time to generate the pizza image;-)
What I want is to check that a file exists, and when it does redirect to another razor page. That shows the pizza when it is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var interval;
        var found = false;
        var doesFileExist = function (fileServerPath) {
            if (found)
                window.location.href = "PreviewOfPizza";
            else
                $.ajax({
                    type: "HEAD",
                    url: fileServerPath,
                    success: function (result) {
                        found = true;
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }, //success: function(result) {
                    error: function() {
                    },
                    timeout:1000 // 1.sec.
                });//$.ajax({
          };//var doesFileExist = function(fileServerPath) {   

          function check () {
             doesFileExist("/images/scans/PizzaA.png");
             doesFileExist("/images/scans/PizzaA.jpg");
          }; // var check = function () {

        interval = setInterval(function () { check(); }, 5000);
     }); //$(document).ready(function () {
 </script>
```

I have tried all kinds of different ways to get the redirect to be called, but for some reason it takes forever, or never happends. I.e. even with the file being on disc. I am wondering if it is due to the interval size and/or timeout specified.

Comment: Ok, I think it is not actually my polling, but the redirection that isn't working ;-)

Comment: see solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just dawned on me, that the problem was the not the ajax call or the  interval, but it was the assigning of the new url to the new pizza preview page.

```
window.location.href =  = "http://"+ window.location.host + 
                          "/PreviewOfPizza";
```

That solved my problem ;-)